# Animation of div position does not result in actual movement

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Cannot figure out why this simple animation will not move (the opacity part works fine). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$("#par").ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({
        right:"200px",
        opacity:".4"
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: is it your div in `relative/absolute/fixed` position? if not change `right` with `margin-right`

Comment: show us your html.. it will be in div's positioning

Comment: div{
height:200px;
width:1000px;
}
p{
position:absolute;
}
#par{
position:relative;
}

Comment: This is the html followed by the css. I have tried both relative and fixed positions as well as margin-right and margin...no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1711712 did you really try with a fixed position for your div ? As in the fiddle I link to ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

> Directional properties (top, right, bottom, left) have no discernible
>   effect on elements if their position style property is static, which
>   it is by default.

This works well if, for example, you set the `position` as fixed, as in [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/mLha9/).

```
<div id=div style="position:fixed">AAA</div>​
```

and then

```
 $("#div").animate({
     right:"200px",
     opacity:".4"
 },2000);
```